# How to returns all public tweets regarding for specific location using tweeter api

Tags: tweets, trend

Is there an API call which will returns all recent public tweets regarding for specific location?

I tried `GET trends/place` but it's **WOEID** not worked for Sri Lanka and Cities.
(Sri Lanka WOEID is 23424778)

I don't want to use tweeter `GET search/tweets.json` endpoint because search based on certain key words.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer. We could not get trends on each and every location using tweeter API 1.1.

you have to check our closest trending place using this API call. For Austalia

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/closest.json?lat=37.781157&long=-122.400612831116
```

the response like be this.

```
    [
  {
    "country": "Australia",
    "countryCode": "AU",
    "name": "Australia",
    "parentid": 1,
    "placeType": {
      "code": 12,
      "name": "Country"
    },
    "url": "http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/23424748",
    "woeid": 23424748
  }
]
```

after that, you can use `GET trends/place`.

even though you cannot use `GET trends/place` for geo-based filtering you can use tweeter search endpoint. if you do not want to filter it by keyword ignore the `q` parameter and use `geocode`parameter. for example,

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?result_type=recent&geocode=5.954920,80.554956,12mi
```

In here mi is miles.